# blocked by CORS :The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *',

Tags: angular, laravel

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PATCH, PUT' );
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers : Content-type, X-Auth-Token, Authorization, Origin');
        return $next($request);
    }
```

I tried to post information in Forms by angular but I got this error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/api/register' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed.
register.component.ts:43 HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://localhost:8000/api/register", ok: false, …}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel 8 ships already with cors support, so you probably already defined the `*` value there.

Check your `config/cors.php` file, it probably it something like this:

```
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
    | or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
    | in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
    |
    | To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
    |
    */

    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => false,

];
```

adjust the `path` list accordingly to your needs

Comment: i've installed the CORS when i created the project like i was doing in my last project in laravel 5.8,
but laravel 8 has automaticaly CORS in config
for that he give me this error
thx i resolved the problem